# Service Fabric: ImmutableList stored in IReliableDictionary returning empty when application upgrades

Tags: c#, azure, service-fabric-stateful, immutable-collections

I am currently working on a Service Fabric stateful service that keeps several `IReliableDictionary` objects. Some of these dictionaries have `ImmutableLists` as values, as recommended by [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-work-with-reliable-collections).

For example, I have an `IReliableDictionary<string,ImmutableList<string>>`. The dictionaries are populated and retrieved from perfectly fine, however when the application is upgraded, all of my immutable lists come back as empty. All other data is intact, and if I switch to `IReliableDictionary<string,List<string>>`, the collection is retained just fine. For the sake of this test, I am populating the list, incrementing the service version number, and hitting "publish > upgrade" on my local cluster. I have tested both 1 and 5 node configuration to the same effect.

Is there some compatibility issue with `ImmutableList` and `IReliableDictionary` that I should be aware about? How do I properly store my state like this? I am happy to share any code as needed, but I am not sure what portions are relevant.

Initialisation on first run and retrieval on subsequent runs:

```
private readonly IReliableDictionary> itemData;
private readonly IReliableDictionary> buildHistory;

public ItemProcessor(IReliableStateManager stateManager, string itemDictionaryName, string historyDictionaryName)
{
    itemData = stateManager.GetOrAddAsync<IReliableDictionary<string, ImmutableList<Item>>>(itemDictionaryName).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
    buildHistory = stateManager.GetOrAddAsync<IReliableDictionary<DateTime, ImmutableList<long>>>(historyDictionaryName).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that, for reasons still a mystery to me, one cannot use `ImmutableList` as a value in `IReliableDictionary`. Instead, one must use `IEnumerable<T>` and set it `.ToImmutableList()` whenever needed.